# Link not clickable until I hover over the bottom of it

Tags: html, css, menu, hyperlink, hover

I have a horizontal menu of links. If I mouseover the links from below, they act totally normal, and the entire link is clickable just like it should be. However, if I mouseover approaching from above or the side, the link is not clickable at all until my mouse reaches the bottom of the link (below the text of the link)... but once I've moused-over the bottom, the entire link is clickable again. Here's the html:

```
<div id="menu">
<a class="menBtn"href="/news.php">NEWS</a>
<a class="menBtn"href="/photos.php">PHOTOS</a>
<a class="menBtn"href="/give.php">ABOUT</a>
<a class="menBtn"href="/give.php">GIVE</a> 
</div>
```

and here's the css:

```
#menu {
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  }

.menBtn {
  padding:.25em .5em;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  font-size:30px;
  color:#c1c3c2;
  }

.menBtn:hover {
  opacity:.75;
  }
```

Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

[EDIT] The only code before the menu is below:

```
  <div id="banner">
    <span id="header">A TITLE</span>     
  </div>

#banner {
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  height:100px;
  top:25px;
  }

#header {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size:40px;
  color:#bdbb94;
  padding:0.25em 0.5em;
  width:30%;
```

}

Comment: Working as expected here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ws96P/ (javascript just for demonstration purposes)

Comment: We cannot troubleshoot this issue with out more code, more specifically what comes before the menu. Something is altering the position/flow of the elements hence the hover issue.

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/anehQ/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. I removed the height value from the banner and added a margin-bottom to push the menu down.